# How does a via stub cause deterministic jitter?

Tags: pcb, signal-integrity, via, jitter

In a PCB, a via stub is the part of a via that is not used to transport the signal between signal layers. A via stub, as far as I know, can damage signal integrity because of signal reflection: at the via stub's resonant frequency (dependent on its length), the signal is strongly attenuated (a problem for high speed signals).

I've heard this called "deterministic jitter", however, and I was wondering why? As per the definition, deterministic jitter refers to a change in phase/periodicity. Here, it seems via stubs keep the phase intact, causing only attenuation.

Comment: why would you think it 'keeps the phase intact'? It is capable of altering the magnitude, and electrical signals are notoriously complex, complex as in a+jb

Comment: First of all, I'm not sure that stub causes jitter.  It may cause a phase or amplitude change, but that is fixed over time.  It's deterministic in the sense that the phase shift or attenuation is solely determined by the geometry of the via stub, and the frequency of interest.  Once the PCB (with the via stub) is built, the phase/attenuation change due to the stub is fixed.

Comment: So from these comments the "deterministic" part is quite clear. I also understand why it would be called "jitter". It just seems like it would then either be "deterministic" something, like amplitude attenuation, or random jitter?